# golang with cgo throws error collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: linux, go, gcc, cgo

I am compiling a golang package, which includes the integration of a shared c library using `cgo`.
Everything builds successfully inside docker images `golang:1.15.15`, `golang:1.16.6`, but since `golang:1.16.7` (also `golang:1.17`) it fails with error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: src/foobar/lib/libXYZ.so: undefined reference to `feenableexcept'
/usr/bin/ld: src/foobar/lib/libXYZ.so: undefined reference to `floor'
...
/usr/bin/ld: src/foobar/lib/libXYZ.so: undefined reference to `memoFree'
/usr/bin/ld: src/foobar/lib/libXYZ.so: undefined reference to `memoMalloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked the golang release notes, and could not find any relevant changes for `cgo`.

I checked versions of gcc and ld, those are all different. I even setup a ubuntu distro with `go1.13.8`, `gcc (Ubuntu 8.4.0-3ubuntu2) 8.4.0` and `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34`, where I run into this issue, so I guess, that `go` goes not cause it.

Do you have any clue or suggestion, how I can find the root cause of this issue? Is it right to check gcc and ld, or which other tools need investigation?

Comment: You could try using a tag with fully qualified host OS such as `golang:1.16.6-alpine3.14` to narrow down the cause. The non-qualified ones just install the latest release of every dependency at the time of build. See e.g. https://hub.docker.com/layers/golang/library/golang/1.16.6-alpine3.14/images/sha256-a8df40ad1380687038af912378f91cf26aeabb05046875df0bfedd38a79b5499?context=explore vs. https://hub.docker.com/layers/golang/library/golang/1.16.6/images/sha256-4516c60e1ec5e24ef54f299c1eb711c9d0f49213e7bcd740e5cd261181a3653b?context=explore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Zyl, I was able to narrow down the problem.

I checked several distributions (bullseye, buster, stretch) and with bullseye, the build failed. In my case, neither the version of `ld` coming from `binutils` nor `gcc` caused the problem.

It seems, that the default settings for handling `DT_NEEDED` tags for the linker have changed. I resolved my problem taking the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117174/2290153 and adding `export CGO_LDFLAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the environment. According to https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/binutils-common/gold.1.en.html this is the default for the `ld.gold` linker, but not for `ld`.

What helped me a lot, was the `-x` flag of the `go build` command to have a look at the gcc command being executed for `cgo`.