# Go build ld: cannot find -l<library_name>

Tags: linux, go, build, debian, ld

I'm trying to build a golang website on `Debian 11` but at build time I get this error:

```
# gocv.io/x/gocv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_gapi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_barcode
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_wechat_qrcode
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_xfeatures2d
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I installed open cv using `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`
and can confirm that opencv is installed:

```
python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
4.6.0
```

In `Debian 10` on another server I used to built the same codebase without any issues

My go version is  `go1.16.7 linux/amd64`

I have tried many things like `export CGO_LDFLAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495750/golang-with-cgo-throws-error-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status) but they did not work.

Also, this might be helpful:  `ld -lzlib --verbose` gives:

```
ld: mode elf_x86_64
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libzlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libzlib.a failed
ld: cannot find -lzlib
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /lib/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/zlib.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libzlib.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/zlib.a failed
```

I have also tried: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/blnks` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34256630/15363841) but still get the same erro.

Appreciate your help to resolve this.

Comment: `opencv-contrib-python ` doesn't  install OpenCV libraries. Use  the command `pip3 show opencv-contrib-python -f` to see the  list of files of the package. You need  to install the  OpenCV yourself.

Comment: @PakUula I built opencv from source using this guid: https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-opencv-debian/ but still get the same error.

Comment: It must  have installed `so`  files  somewhere inside `/usr/local/lib`. Check it. Use `sudo ldconfig` to update  ld cache.

Comment: Right, after a complete rebuild using this https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html the problem is resolved. Thanks for your tips dude.